# JavaFx System Tray is not supported

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17 and Java Fx on Win 10 machine. I tried to use the code below but for some reason it says it is not supported.Any idea please?

```
   if (!java.awt.SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420903/systemtray-not-supported-on-windows-10

Comment: This may solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869075/tray-icon-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04/40284858#40284858

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes I have tried the followings but still did not work out. For some reason. I am using spring boot.       SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyAwtApplication.class);
        builder.headless(false).run(args);      System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");     -Djava.awt.headless=false as an arg